# WebJobs not stopping by using the Rest API Post method within powershell script - Getting Error 403 - This web app is stopped

Tags: azure, rest, powershell, api, azure-powershell

When switching slots withing azure on my application, i am trying to stop the webjobs on the "stopped" server as they seem to keep running within azure. However when i use the invoke-restmethod within my powershell script, it comes back with Error 403 - This web app is stopped, but on my azure site it is still running. Frustratingly i can use the method when using postman, but when it comes to my script with the identical request it is not stopping the webjobs.

I have tried running this particular script within powershell, but it wont run due to the stated error. The Get method works fine in powershell, bringing back the application, but the stop rest call does not.

```
function StopWebJob($slotToStop) {
    # Get an access token to authenticate the web jobs API
    Write-Verbose -Verbose "Getting an access token..."
    $stopToken = Get-BasicAuthToken $slotToStop
    Write-Verbose -Verbose "Got access token."

    #Generate a header to start/stop the web jobs using the access token
    $stopHeader = @{ 'Authorization'= $stopToken }

    Write-Verbose -Verbose "Checking job status..."
    $getJob = "https://$WebAppName-$slotToStop.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/continuouswebjobs/{myWebJob}/"
    $getJobResult = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $getJob -Headers $stopHeader -Method Get

    If($getJobResult.status -ne "Stopped") {
        Write-Verbose -Verbose "Stopping job..."
        $stop = "https://$WebAppName-$slotToStop.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/continuouswebjobs/{MyWebJob}/stop"
        Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $stop -Headers $stopHeader -Method Post
        Write-Verbose -Verbose "Job stopped."
    } else {    
        Write-Verbose -Verbose "Job is already stopped."
    }
}
```

When the slot switches, I expect the Job on the "down" slot to be stopped via the rest api.

Comment: Sorry, Thanks for any help with regards to this! I'm not rude really :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can reproduce your issue, looks you missed the `-UserAgent` in the `Invoke-RestMethod`.

[image]

It should be like below, add the `-UserAgent "powershell/1.0"` to your command.

```
Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $stop -Headers $stopHeader -Method Post -UserAgent "powershell/1.0"
```

---

Then it will work fine, you could refer to my complete sample.

```
$username = "`$website"
$password = "pwd"
$base64AuthInfo = [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(("{0}:{1}" -f $username, $password)))

Write-Verbose -Verbose "Checking job status..."
$getJob = "https://<webappname>-slot1.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/continuouswebjobs/webjob1"
$getJobResult = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $getJob -Headers @{Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo)} -Method Get

If($getJobResult.status -ne "Stopped") {
        Write-Verbose -Verbose "Stopping job..."
        $stop = "https://<webappname>-slot1.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/continuouswebjobs/webjob1/stop"
        Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $stop -Headers @{Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo)} -Method Post -UserAgent "powershell/1.0"
        Write-Verbose -Verbose "Job stopped."
    } else {    
        Write-Verbose -Verbose "Job is already stopped."
    }
```

[image]

Comment: Awesome that has worked! I dont suppose you know why the get doesn't require a user agent but the post does? But tha is again! Saved me from a lot of headache lol